# Login Review for Facebook Login

Tags: facebook-login

I implemented the Facebook Login for my Flutter app.
Everything works as expected but when I want to login via Facebook the following warning is displayed:

> Submit for Login Review. Some of the permissions below have not been
> approved for use by Facebook. Submit for review now or learn more.

[image]

I think this is because of the additional email permission I added which is needed by firebase authentication.

But how can I submit for a review?
If I click on the link I get to the following page:

[image]

On this page I click on the blue button "Request Permissions or Feature". After that I am on the following page:

[image]

**What should I do next to submit for a review to remove the warning on the login page?**

If I click on edit the following screen is displayed:

[image]

When I hover the mouse over the requirements of email there is only business verification displayed which I have already done.

On the overview page of all apps there is shown that my app is already in live mode not in debug mode and there are no actions required.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What scopes is your integration requesting?

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you for your fast replay. Only email. The code looks like that: final result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(permissions: ['email']);

Comment: The review process will not allow certain features if your SDK os out of date .. Make sure you are all up to date as well

Comment: @Zak Hm okay... I am not sure why the console think I am using an old SDK Version. I wanted to post a new question for that on stackoverflow. I am using flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.11. Not the newest because there is a problem with another dependency but the newest I can use right now in my app. In my previous app the Facebook developer console did not show this message with exactly the same code.

Comment: @Zak But I will try it with the newest plugin version flutter_facebook_auth: ^6.0.0